# Spring webflow transition empty response

Tags: spring-webflow, thymeleaf

In my page I have a select list that, when one option is selected, triggers an event in my webflow.

```
<transition on="triggeredChange">
    <evaluate expression="myClass.myMethod(flowScope.myData)"
              result="flowScope.myData.item.property" />
    <render fragments="idOfDivToRender" />
</transition>
```

The event is triggered and if I set a debug point in myClass.myMethod it appears that the execution has no error, but in the page I get this error:

> Received empty response with no Spring redirect headers. If this is
>   intentional set the response status code to 204 or 205.

If I manually refresh the page I can see that `flowScope.myData.item.property` has the new value (as expected), so it appears that somehow the error is in the fragment rendering.

What am I missing?

For additional info, the div with `id="idOfDivToRender"` is inside a `<th:block th:fragment="firstFragment">` because the page is very long and complex (they want it that way and I can't simplify it) and for readability we chose to create a main page whith a lot of `<th:block th:replace="pages/firstFragment:: firstFragment"></th:block>` in it.

Comment: post your thymeleaf + webflow configs + fragments config

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you did not configure thymeleaf + webflow + fragments correctly. Please post your config + versions.

or you are not making the correct ajax call to trigger the fragment to be returned. Make sure you passing the following **REQUIRED** parameters in your request to trigger to return the fragment html only .

```
_eventId=idOfDivToRender
```

and

```
 ajaxSource=true
```

Use something like Firebug or whatever testing utility to test the response is being returned correctly ( status 200 with the expected contents of the fragment)

if you are still not receiving your expected response then I suspect your configuration is incorrect.